# What is Type of Enum when it stored into Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, expression

I am getting Expression x=>x.SomeAttribute

Attribute can be of any type.
I am taking type of property from expression.
For normal primitive properties it gives me right values like int,string... etc.
But for Enum it give me MyEnum.
I want to execute getExpression method for Enum. So what to pass as TResult.

```
public enum TestEnum
    {
        first = 0,
        second = 1
    }

Public Class A 
    {
         public int TestInt {get;set;}
         public string TestString {get;set;}
         public TestEnum EnumDemo { get; set; }
    }



    x=>x.TestInt;
    getExpression<TSource, int>(expression)// when SomeAttribute is integer

    x=>x.TestString;
    getExpression<TSource, string>(expression) // when SomeAttribute  is string

    x=>x.EnumDemo ;
    getExpression<TSource, Enum>(expression) // when SomeAttribute is Enum, It reruns null



private Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> getExpression<TSource, TResult>(Expression expression)
     {
          var x = expression as Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>>;       
           return x;
     }
```

Comment: I assume that you're talking about *properties*. There is a concept in C#/.NET called [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) and it appears to have nothing to do with the question you're asking.

Comment: TMember is TResult right ... ?

Comment: post how you create expression variable

Comment: i post the expressions as well

Comment: Please take the time to properly format your question. It will help others help you.

Comment: couldn't get it to work... 
I'll try again later

Comment: no its not working still

Answer (score 1):

`int` is the underlying type for [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) therefore

```
getExpression<TSource, int>(expression);
```

Will work.

Comment: he can also explicitly declare the enum type.

Comment: @eranotzap they could, however, that would mean a separate call for each enum type, my assumption is the OP doesn't want to do that. It's simple enough to retrieve it as `int` and cast it to the expected `enum` type.

Comment: post your enum please.

Comment: @HemantMalpote  

Type enumType = enumValue.GetType();
Type underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);

Comment: As i am having expression. How would i get the enum value. I don't want to invoke expression in this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68205/discussion-between-hemant-malpote-and-eran-otzap).

Comment: @HemantMalpote sorry but now you are saying you *don't* want to pull the enum via the expression? That's not what you are asking in the question.

Comment: @James : Actually i am just creating expression for AutoMapper. This expression will executed run time.